# what is the difference between "send" and "exp_send" command in TCL EXPECT?

Tags: tcl, expect

what is the difference between "send" and "exp_send" command in TCL EXPECT?

Can anyone explain me the differences between these 2 commands ?

And when can we use the perticular one ?

Comment: "send" is Tk's and "exp_send" is Expect's

Comment: if Tk is loaded, its "send" api command will take precedence. It is wise to always use "exp_send" when calling Expect's "send".

Answer (score 4):

They are the same. Usually.

Expect always* creates 2 versions of its commands:

- One named `exp_something`
- The other one `something`

The reason is that other commands from other extensions could have commands with the same name, like Tk's [`send`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/send.htm)

This approach is deprecated now, if you write your own extension use namespaces and export the commands. The application that uses your stuff can then import the commands it needs.

If you write an extension that uses Expect, always call the `exp_*` commmands. This makes it possible to create an application that uses Tk's `send` (directly or indirect from an other extension) and your extension.

<sub>* a short search resulted in the following commands that don't have an `exp_*` alternative:
`_close.pre_expect expect_background expect_after expect_before expect_tty prompt1 prompt2 expect_user expect`</sub>